# Search for a partial string in text and extract numbers from lines above and below the matched pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that will search based on a string and if it founds even a partial match. I can get extract numbers from lines (2 lines) above and below the matched string or substring.

My text is:

```
Subtotal AED1,232.20
AED61.61
VAT
5 % Tax:
RECEIPT TOTAL: AED1.293.81
```

I wish to search for the word `VAT` and extract all numbers from two lines above and below it.

Expected output:

```
AED1,232.20
AED61.61
5 % 
AED1.293.81
```

I am able to extract the entire content but I need the numbers, AED can be dropped or ignored.

My regex is:

```
((.*\n){2}).*vat(.*\n.*\n.*)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
(?:[a-zA-Z:]*([0-9,.]+)[a-zA-Z:]*)\n(?:[a-zA-Z:]*([0-9,.]+)[a-zA-Z:]*)\nVAT\n(?:[a-zA-Z:]*([0-9,.]+)[a-zA-Z:]*).*\n[^0-9]*(?:[a-zA-Z:]*([0-9,.]+)[a-zA-Z:]*)
```

This regex can seem too complex or long, but it has better control and returns only numbers, it will be his work.

[Regex Demo](https://pythex.org/?regex=(%3F%3A%5Ba-zA-Z%3A%5D*(%5B0-9%2C.%5D%2B)%5Ba-zA-Z%3A%5D*)%5Cn(%3F%3A%5Ba-zA-Z%3A%5D*(%5B0-9%2C.%5D%2B)%5Ba-zA-Z%3A%5D*)%5CnVAT%5Cn(%3F%3A%5Ba-zA-Z%3A%5D*(%5B0-9%2C.%5D%2B)%5Ba-zA-Z%3A%5D*).*%5Cn%5B%5E0-9%5D*(%3F%3A%5Ba-zA-Z%3A%5D*(%5B0-9%2C.%5D%2B)%5Ba-zA-Z%3A%5D*)&test_string=Subtotal%20AED1%2C232.20%0AAED61.61%0AVAT%0A5%20%25%20Tax%3A%0ARECEIPT%20TOTAL%3A%20AED1.293.81&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Comment: @M_Arora this will works with multiple VAT [here](https://pythex.org/?regex=(%3F%3A%5Ba-zA-Z%3A%5D*(%5B0-9%2C.%5D%2B)%5Ba-zA-Z%3A%5D*)%5Cn(%3F%3A%5Ba-zA-Z%3A%5D*(%5B0-9%2C.%5D%2B)%5Ba-zA-Z%3A%5D*)%5CnVAT%5Cn(%3F%3A%5Ba-zA-Z%3A%5D*(%5B0-9%2C.%5D%2B)%5Ba-zA-Z%3A%5D*).*%5Cn%5B%5E0-9%5D*(%3F%3A%5Ba-zA-Z%3A%5D*(%5B0-9%2C.%5D%2B)%5Ba-zA-Z%3A%5D*)&test_string=Subtotal%20AED1%2C232.20%0AAED61.61%0AVAT%0A5%20%25%20Tax%3A%0ARECEIPT%20TOTAL%3A%20AED1.293.81%0A%0A%0ASubtotal%20AED1%2C232.20%0AAED61.61%0AVAT%0A5%20%25%20Tax%3A%0ARECEIPT%20TOTAL%3A%20AED1.293.81&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex in `python`:

```sh
((?:^.*\d.*\n){0,2})VAT((?:\n.*\d.*){0,2})
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OhBxxy/1/)

**RegEx Details:**

- `((?:^.*\d.*\n){0,2})`: Match 2 leading lines that must contain at least a digit
- `VAT`: match text `VAT`
- `((?:\n.*\d.*){0,2})`: Match 2 trailing lines that must contain at least a digit

Comment: [here](https://pythex.org/?regex=((%3F%3A%5E%5CD*%5Cd.*%5Cn)%7B0%2C2%7D)VAT((%3F%3A%5Cn%5CD*%5Cd.*)%7B0%2C2%7D)&test_string=Subtotal%20AED1%2C232.20%0AAED61.61%0AVAT%0A5%20%25%20Tax%3A%0ARECEIPT%20TOTAL%3A%20AED1.293.81&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0) it seems not to work

Comment: It will work. You just need to click on `MULTILINE` button

Comment: yes, but it returns also lot of letters and not only the numbers

Comment: @LeonardoScotti One small change is to be made in the second capturing group ```((?:\D*\d.*){0,2}```. It should work now

Comment: @anubhava If the word ```VAT``` comes more than once in my string and I want to extract numbers both times. What change should be made? This gives me the result of the first match only. I am using ```re.findall(regex, string)```

Comment: @LeonardoScotti: Your expected match shows many non-digits like `AED1,232.20` and `5 %`. You can post process output of above regex to get rid of unwanted text anyway you want.

Comment: Please check updated answer and new demo. It must be used in `re.findall` to get all the matches

Comment: I wud like to know the reason of downvote to improve this answer further

Answer (score 0):

This regex is tailor-made for your input text and expected output:

```
r'.* (AED\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d{2})\n(AED\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d{2})\nVAT\n(\d{1,2} %) Tax:\n.* (AED\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d{2})'
```

[Your required Regex](https://pythex.org/?regex=.*%20(AED%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D(%3F%3A%2C%5Cd%7B3%7D)*%5C.%5Cd%7B2%7D)%5Cn(AED%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D(%3F%3A%2C%5Cd%7B3%7D)*%5C.%5Cd%7B2%7D)%5CnVAT%5Cn(%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D%20%25)%20Tax%3A%5Cn.*%20(AED%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D(%3F%3A%2C%5Cd%7B3%7D)*%5C.%5Cd%7B2%7D)&test_string=Subtotal%20AED1%2C232.20%0AAED61.61%0AVAT%0A5%20%25%20Tax%3A%0ARECEIPT%20TOTAL%3A%20AED1%2C293.81%0A%0ASubtotal%20AED12%2C345.67%0AAED1%2C234.57%0AVAT%0A10%20%25%20Tax%3A%0ARECEIPT%20TOTAL%3A%20AED13%2C580.24%0A&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

It outputs exactly the text you want, without extra words.

It also works with more than one "VAT" in your input text.

### Regex Logics:

- `(AED\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d{2})`  Match currency code and amount (in one group)
- `(\d{1,2} %)`   Match VAT %. Supports 1 to 2 digits.  You can further enhance it to support decimal point.

Note that the proper regex for currency amount (with comma as thousand separator and exactly 2 decimal points) should be as follows:

```
r'\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d{2}'
```

[with (?: expr) to indicate nontagged group so that this subgroup will not be tagged as a match for your re.findall function call.]

In case your input supports currency codes other than 'AED', you can replace 'AED' with [A-Z]{3} as currency code should normally be in 3-character capital letters.

Comment: This works perfectly for this case, but I have different words in the lines surrounding the keyword. Hence, I cannot add words like ```Receipt Total```, ```Subtotal``` etc in the regex

Comment: In this case, you can readily substitute the fixed words (together with punctuation marks) with the .*   I have edited the answer for this update.

Comment: Have you solved your problem yet @M_Arora ?   Anything you need help further from here ?  If no, is there any of the answers here you think fulfill your requirement ?  If there is any, please accept the answer.  You can upvote any answer you think helpful too, if not already done so.